# How to use findViewById in custom class? (Android)

Tags: java, android, button

I'm trying to initialize some buttons in my constructor for a class I made:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < remotes.getRemote(0).getButtonsCount(); i++)
    {
        buttonsUI[i] = (Button)findViewById(buttonsUI[i].getId());
        buttonsUI[i].setOnClickListener(this);
    }
```

but `findViewById` is not recognized. Do I need to use extend `MainActivity` on my class or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Go and search the web and docs for Inflater.

Comment: you will need Context to call `findViewById`

Comment: is it your adapter class??

Answer (score 2):

You will need the activity context to call that method. When you create the class in activity, pass `this` as the context by using a constructor. save the context in class member variable and use it in class methods.

Comment: So my class is supposed to be inside MainActivity? I've had it outside of it this whole time...

Comment: You can declare your class in a separate file. Only it's first instantiation should be inside some Activity.

Comment: Okay now my constructor passes an activity type and when I instantiate it in my activity I pass 'this'. I've got findViewById working by using just putting activity.findViewById but can I do anything for the 'setOnClickListener'?

Comment: See [documentation][1] for setting onClickListener


  [1]: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button.html

Answer (score 1):

No you don't need to extend Activity.
Whatever you are doing, just stop for a minute. Because you need to learn a few lessons on Android Application Framework, which contains details that **you need in this specific case:** `Inflater Service` and `Context`. You can search and there are plenty of resources on [Android Developer](http://developer.android.com) website.

Looks like you are at the beginning of the road, and to be frank, the **best place to start is** watching [Inside Android Application Framework](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TkPiXRNee7A) on Google IO 2008. Go and devour that video.

I wish I had seen it before beginning Android application development.

Answer (score 0):

You Just pass the Context of the application where you are going to add the Button send the Context of the arguments for this Constructor and use like below....

```
 ClassName(Context contextMainActivity)
{

     for (int i = 0; i < remotes.getRemote(0).getButtonsCount(); i++)
     {
        buttonsUI[i] = (Button) contextMainActivity.findViewById(buttonsUI[i].getId());
        buttonsUI[i].setOnClickListener(contextMainActivity);
     }
}
```